# How to Serve 4 Images (Blobs) from Mysql using PHP in a single HTTP Response?

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am trying to display 4 images using PHP and MySQL database. I have to display the 4 images as rows.

I use the table cars with fields (`id_car`, `car_image1`, `car_image2`, `car_image3`, `car_image4`), with all the images being blob datatype.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("cars_database");
$sql = "SELECT car_image1, car_image2, car_image3, car_image4 FROM cars WHERE id_car='$id'";
$result = mysql_query("$sql");

mysql_close($link);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    echo $row['car_image1'];
    echo $row['car_image2'];
    echo $row['car_image3'];
    echo $row['car_image4'];    
}
```

I can only display 1 image and not the other images. Since I am a newbie to this technology I need help.

Comment: Check the paths of images from 2 to 4. Are they correct. Open it in IE and if you see broken images then you there is some problem in paths

Comment: With `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` you *can* only display ***one image***, the browser will only parse the first image and drop the rest (or crashes even depending how well it is programmed). What you can do is create one image out of four images and then serve that one image. You can do that with an image library like gd: http://php.net/book.image - But it's not clear from your question what you want exactly.

Comment: Also, security issues with SQL injection exist with the example code .  Either sanitize  'id' , or use prepared statements (better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how HTTP works (at least, current version): you cannot have a URL that points to more than one resource simultaneously. Your script needs to send *one* image.

Simply, call it *four* times:

```
<img src="/get-image.php?id=1">
<img src="/get-image.php?id=2">
<img src="/get-image.php?id=3">
<img src="/get-image.php?id=4">
```

Comment: Well, you can also create one image out of four as this is PHP, so probably that was asked for? For me so far just the question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define path for images.

```
<?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
     header('Content-type: image/jpeg');    
?>  
    <img src="path<?php echo $row['car_image1']; ?>" alt="" />
    <img src="path<?php echo $row['car_image2']; ?>" alt="" />
    <img src="path<?php echo $row['car_image3']; ?>" alt="" />
    <img src="path<?php echo $row['car_image4']; ?>" alt="" />
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: If you want to insert inline images into HTML you can't just insert the raw binary data. You need to encode it as a proper [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). But I would not recommend it as a general method to insert pictures.